# How can I hide the header of the PageControl TabSheets in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, tpagecontrol

I wonder how can I hide the headers of the TabSheets in PageControl component. I want make a creator e.g to build your champion where you can choose some stuff on the pages. TabSheets will be change every 10 s by Timer. In Google I can find only how hide TabSheet(with contents). I want hide only header of the TabSheets e.gTabSheet1 and so on.
I'm working in C++ Builder.
Greetings,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hide every page of the `TPageControl` (`TabVisible` property of the `TabSheet`) and you can still show the `Tabsheet` **in code**, by changing the `ActivePage` or `ActivePageIndex` properties of the page control.

The Timer can call the [`SelectNextPage`](https://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ComCtrls_TPageControl_SelectNextPage.html) method to programmatically change the active page:

```
PageControl1->SelectNextPage(true, false);
```

EDIT

A simple form (`Form1`) with a `TPageControl` (as appears in the designer):

[image: TPageControl in the designer]

The code to hide the header:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
  for (int i(0); i < PageControl1->PageCount; ++i)
    PageControl1->Pages[i]->TabVisible = false;

  // You can show the TabSheet programmatically changing the active page.
  PageControl1->ActivePage = TabSheet1;
}
```

The code to select the next page:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  PageControl1->SelectNextPage(true, false);
}
```

The wizard-like effect (at runtime):

[image]

---

Recent versions of C++Builder have the [`TCardPanel` control](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_the_Card_Panel_Component). It's a set of pages, like the `TPageControl`, **with no tabs**. You display one page at a time (each hosting its own controls) and it has built in support for swiping pages using a gesture.

Comment: Yes I know. I call the SelectNextPage method. I still have the header of the TabSheet. I want only the Sheet with content without header e.g TabSheet1

Comment: Edit*
Now I do not have headers of the TabSheets but also I do not see the content of the TabSheets

Comment: @Lukas I added a small example

Comment: Just for the record - this didn't work for me until I had PageControl1->ActivePageIndex = 0; (or PageControl1->ActivePage = TabSheet1; as above)

Comment: This also works for me in Delphi 5